# How to shuffle a deck of cards using Java (trying to use hashmap, not working)?

Tags: java, android, collections, hashmap

I have a `hashmap<Integer, Card>` `Card` is a class. I have initialized the `hashmap` with `keys` from 0-51 and the values are array of `Card`, as follows

```
Card [] card = new Card[52]
for (int i=1; i<=13; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
        card[++index] = new Card( ((i*10)+j) );
```

and I populate the `hashmap` as follows:

```
for (int i=1; i<=13; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
        deck.put( ++key, card[++index] );
```

Now, what I want to do is to `shuffle` the values side of the `hashmap`, i do not want,for an example, the key[1] corresponds to card[0] and key[1] corresponds to card[1]. I want, for an exampel, the key[1] corresponds to card[38]. I want the values side to be shuffled. I tried the following:

`Collections.shuffle(card,new Random());` But it seems it accepts only `ArrayList` and `List`.

Comment: HashMap has an internal structure. If you shuffle'd it, it would no longer be a valid data-structure. In short, you can't.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thank you very much. can I shuffle an array?I ean , is there any built-in method for schuffling an array?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to shuffle a map? It does *not* have positional info, you have to build a couple of layers of abstraction to do this, and you would end up with a crap version of a list

Comment: You can shuffle a List. Put your cards in a list instead of a map. Because your key is a number you can do the same with the list (list.get(index))

Comment: I am not sure why you are using a <Integer, Card> map when you could get the same functionality and a bit more from a `List<Card> list = new ArrayList<Card>();` (of course, I guess it only works as a map if you initialize all values at first in order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I shuffle an array?

Yes. Here's one way.

```
Integer[] t = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(t));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
```

Answer (score 4):

HashMaps do not have a predictable order, and shuffling an unordered data structure doesn't make sense. From the Java reference docs:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

If you are using keys from 0-51, you should just add all of the cards to an ArrayList. Then you can use `Collections.shuffle(arrayList)`

Answer (score 1):

You should consider adjusting your design to include a `Deck` and `Card` class. Examples are shown below. Your "encoding" for a card has a potential flaw 10*suit + card will have suit 0 card 13 have the same value as suit 1, card 3. If you want to compare two cards to see which "wins", you should add a method to the Card class that does this.

Try this:

**Deck Class**

```
package com.example.cards;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Deck {
    // Class fields
    // Object fields
    private Integer[] deckOrder;
    private int nextCard;
    private Card[] cards;

    public Deck() {
        deckOrder = new Integer[52];
        cards = new Card[52];
        for (int i=0; i < deckOrder.length; i++) {
            deckOrder[i] = i;
            cards[i] = new Card(i/13,i % 13);
        }
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(deckOrder));
        nextCard = 0;
    }

    public Card deal() {
        if (nextCard < deckOrder.length) {
            nextCard++;
            return cards[deckOrder[nextCard-1]];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Card Class**

```
package com.example.cards;

public class Card {
    // Class fields
    public final static String[] suit = {"Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs"};
    public final static String[] card = {"Ace","King","Queen","Jack","Ten","Nine"
                                        ,"Eight","Seven","Six","Five","Four"
                                        ,"Three","Two"};
    // Object fields
    private int suitIndex;
    private int cardIndex;

    public Card(int suit, int card) {
        suitIndex = suit;
        cardIndex = card;
    }
    public int getSuitIndex() { return suitIndex;}
    public int getCardIndex() { return cardIndex;}
    public String getSuit() { return suit[suitIndex];}
    public String getCard() { return card[cardIndex];}

    public int getEncodedCard() { return 100*suitIndex + cardIndex;}
}
```

**Test driver**

```
package com.example.cards;
public class TestShuffle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck myDeck = new Deck();
        for (int deal = 1; deal < 3; deal++) {
            System.out.println("======================Deal " + deal);
            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
                Card nextCard = myDeck.deal();
                System.out.println("Card " + i + ". " + nextCard.getCard()
                        + " of " + nextCard.getSuit() + "(encoded "
                        + nextCard.getEncodedCard() + ")");
            }
            myDeck.shuffle();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Map<String, Object> x = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    x.put("x", 1); x.put("y", 2); x.put("z", 3); x.put("w", 4);
    System.out.println(x);
    List<Object> vs = new ArrayList<Object>(x.values());
    Collections.shuffle(vs);
    System.out.println(vs);
    Iterator<Object> vIter = vs.iterator();
    for (String k : x.keySet()) x.put(k, vIter.next());
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

output :

```
{w=4, x=1, y=2, z=3}
[2, 3, 1, 4]
{w=2, x=3, y=1, z=4}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is extract your key value pairs as a `List` of `Map.Entry` and shuffle it and put your `Map.Entry` values in the cleared map

```
  Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Card> cardEntrySet= deck.entrySet();
    List<Map.Entry<Integer,Card> cardsEntryList = new ArrayList<>(cardEntrySet);
    Collections.shuffle(cardsEntryList);
    deck.clear();

    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Card> entry :cardsEntryList){
      deck.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: There is no gaurantee though that it will work because HashMap is an unordered data structure